# Arch Linux: GRUB does not load after installation

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, grub, mbr

I have installed windows 10 in my laptop in BIOS Legacy mode.I have 3 primary partitions including the Windows partition and have extended partition with 2 more logical partitions.

Now for installing Arch-Linux I created 4 more logical partitions for /boot,root,swap and /home in that order under the extended partition.
So this is how it looks:

```
sda1 primary 163gb ntfs
sda2 primary 175gb ntfs
sda3 primary 175gb ntfs
sda4 extended 185gb
    sda5 logical 100gb ntfs
    sda6 logical 10gb ntfs
    sda7 *(boot) logical 400mb ext4 
    sda8 (root) logical 23gb ext4
    sda9 (swap) logical 4gb linux-swap
    sda10 (home) logical 50gb ext4
```

I have an arch linux live usb through which i booted and installed the base system.I installed grub and then restarted. Now the problem is the grub wont load and system is into infinie restart loop just showing this:

[image: exiting pxe rom]

then **exiting pxe rom and restarts back to this screen infinitely**.

Now when i select Run Installed OS from live usb options it just shows syslinux screen for a second and returns to the options.
When I press tab to edit boot setting for installed os, it shows: 
**`.com32 boot/syslinux/chain.c32 hd0 0` 
when I change it to hd1 0 the grub loads and everything is fine.**

But this is temporary..Every time I have to do this using live usb for getting grub.
Why does this happen and what should i do to get grub permanently?

Note: The installation went fine and fdisk -l showed this error alone:
**partition 4 does not start at a physical boundary**.

Comment: what instructions did you follow to install Arch ? understand that dual-booting with windows isn't just straight-forward

Comment: @niceman I followed the Arch Beginners' guide.[https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners'_guide]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the cause of the problem was exactly but I fixed it by booting from a windows 10 live disk and performing a **startup repair**.
That solved the problem and now I get GRUB on booting the system.